# $B^{-1}$ has one positive entry per row if $B$ is invertible and nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm a little stuck into a question of the book "Linear Programming and Network Flows":

Let $B$ be an invertible matrix with nonnegative entries. Show that every row of $B^{-1}$ has at least one positive entry.

I tried to show that the elements in the diagonal should be positive in $B^{-1}$ when doing elementary operations into $B$. But I was not able to go very far...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** if it were not to be the case, we would have a row with **all** negative entries.

> Suppose that this occurs at row $j$. Then we must have $1 = I_{jj} = (B^{-1}B)_{jj} = \sum_{s}B^{-1}_{js}B_{js},$ which is absurd since the right hand side is negative (recall that by hypotehsis it is $B_{js}^{-1}B_{js} \leq 0$ for all $s$).

Answer (score 1):

Seeking a contradiction, suppose that $B^{-1}$ has a row $r$ whose entries are nonpositive. The equation $B^{-1}B$ implies that $r\cdot b=1$ for one of the columns $b$ of $B$. Since each entry in $r$ is $\leq 0$ and each entry in $b$ is $\geq 0$, it follows that each term in $r\cdot b$ is $\leq 0$. Thus $1=r\cdot b\leq 0$, a contradiction.